# RTRIM Syntax error

Tags: java, sql, trim

I m using sql server 2005. I want to use RTRIM function for column Name having datatype Varchar(20) in sql server 2005 but it is giving an error(incorrect syntax near'(').

```
           try
            {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:project","sa","123456");
                PreparedStatement stmt= con.prepareStatement("insert into driver (RTRIM(Name),Address,Email,Homeph,Cellph,Startdate,Hourlyrate,Image) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                stmt.setString(1,tx_name.getText());
                stmt.setString(2,tx_address.getText());
                stmt.setString(3,tx_email.getText());
                stmt.setInt(4,Integer.parseInt(tx_homeph.getText()));
                stmt.setInt(5,Integer.parseInt(tx_cellph.getText()));
                String date=cb_date.getSelectedItem().toString()+"-"+cb_month.getSelectedItem().toString()+"-"+cb_year.getSelectedItem().toString();
                stmt.setString(6,date);
                stmt.setInt(7,Integer.parseInt(tx_hourlyrate.getText()));
                stmt.setString(8,tx_image.getText());
                stmt.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,"Data Saved","Save",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
            catch(Exception en)
            {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(f,en);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use RTRIM on the VALUE bing inserted, not the column name.

[RTRIM (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx)

> Returns a character string after truncating all trailing blanks.

Comment: Ok and How can i do this?

Comment: You are in full control of the parameter, so trim it in JAVA before you insert it.

Comment: Or do `RTRIM(?)` in the `VALUES` part